# AZ CLI login using Service Principal fails from specific computer

Tags: azure

I have posted previously about `az login` using a Service Principal failing with the error `No subscriptions found` and I have run across others that have had similar issues. Capability seems shaky for some reason. What I am seeing now that has me scratching my head is when I run a script I have that does an `az login` with a service principal from my desktop computer it works fine...no issues. When I run the same script from my laptop, the login fails with the `No subscriptions found` error. What I have tried on the laptop:

- Checked AZ CLI version...same as desktop
- Ran `az account clear` to make sure everything was cleared out
- Deleted Service Principal from AAD and recreated from laptop

I even ran `az account clear` on my desktop to make sure it was not working simply because it was cached and even after the clear, the `az login` worked fine.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you specify the tenant with `--tenant <tenant>` for `az login`?

Comment: @JoyWang yes...using the same script on each computer. This is the line I am using: `az login --service-principal --username $acr_sp_appid --password $acr_sp_secret --tenant $tenant_Id --subscription $subscription_Id`

Comment: Any chance you have conditional access policies set up, or that one of the computers is a work computer while the other is a personal one? Or maybe one is on a VPN while the other isn't?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a Role to the Service Principle, or add the flag `--allow-no-subscriptions`.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted resolution for this under following thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66108965/1712969

you might want to try command with this flag  "--allow-no-subscriptions"