# Azure login for tenant failing for Az app/principal with No subscription found message

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an azure account called account1 where I create an App/Principal that is across tenants visibility. I then give it some API permissions. I have another azure account account2 where I need to access resources using this app. I complete the admin consent flow for account2 by going to the following url
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<account2 domain>/adminconsent?client_id=cid1`

The flow finishes and I get the tenant id back as say `tid2`. When I try to login from command prompt with app creds to access account2, I get an error
(it was working before and suddenly stopped working)

`az login --service-principal --username cid1 --password "pwd" --tenant tid2`

Error:
No subscriptions found for cid1.

Comment: I got the same message with a single tenant. The reason was that the az login needed 2FA/MFA but didn't ask for it. I logged into the Azure Web console and then az login worked

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: In the chat we found the issue had something to do with the terminal app used on Mac. After using the native terminal, the login was successful and the other terminal app worked as well.

You need to assign RBAC roles to the service principal in account 2.
You can do that through the Access Control (IAM) tab of the subscription by adding the necessary role to the app.

Comment: I am not sure @juunas, why yiu say that. Until like 2 hours ago, the app consent flow would finish and login will work. I have to assign this role where? I have assigned roles at resource group level and all but what IAM role are you suggesting and why?

Comment: Ah, resource group level assignment should also work :)

Comment: Could you add that info to the question, e.g. "I've assigned X and Y roles to the SP on resource groups in account2"?

Comment: I am totally not sure what you are asking or suggesting. If you explain a bit more I can add the info. I did only what I wrote above in the Q so far, nothing more

Comment: What do you want to access from account2 with the SP?

Comment: When I create an App, I give a set of API permissions to the app and the app will just make those api calls into the account2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219118/discussion-between-curiousengineer-and-juunas).

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if you created a service principal and granted it access permissions to specific azure resources within a susbcription, in which case your sp will not have access to whole susbcription. I had same issue as you were facing until I tried flag "--allow-no-subscriptions". Following worked fine for me from within a container to read and update a certificate from/to azure key vault, where I granted sp read,list and import permissions.

az login --allow-no-subscriptions --service-principal --username cid1 --password "pwd" --tenant tid2

Answer (score 0):

Granting "Reader" on resource group level is enough to resolve this error.